# joint distribution function is min(U,V)

Tags: statistics

> If $U$ and $V$ are uniform $(0,1)$ random variables whose joint distribution
> function is $\min(u,v)$, then $P(U=V)=1$. And if the joint distribution is $\max(u+v-1 ,0)$, then $P(U+V=1)=1$.

Why is that?

Comment: If $P(U=V)=1$ then the joint distribution function restricted to $(0,1)^2$ is $\min(u,v)$ and conversely this function *completely determines* probability measure $P_{U,V}$. So it also determines the value of $P_{U,V}(\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\})=P(U=V)$.

Comment: @drhab sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Do you agree that in the first case the joint distribution function of $(U,V)$ is exactly the same as the joint distribution function of $(U,U)$? This allows us to concude that $P(U=V)=P(U=U)=1$.